# Write chunks of binary file, from not start of file in C#

Tags: c#, console-application

### The why:

I have a list of hashes (that is created from 2 source files that is split into a number of chunks, so that chunk1 has hash1, chunk2 has hash2 and so on) that I would like to match with chunks of the files.

The issue is that one of the chunks match the end of file1 and beginning of file2.
I do not know how much of file2 is in the chunk with both of the files, but I know that a hash value will match a chunk of file2 that starts at an offset from the beginning (and from that point onwards the hashes will match the chunks of file2).

So my thought process is to take a chunk of file2, make a hash, compare: If match => Keep chunking and hashing. If no match: Offset the start of the chunk with 1 byte (meaning start of file + 1 byte), hash, compare, offset the start of the chunk with 2 bytes, hash, compare and so on until a match is found.

*The chunk size (N) and hash algorithm is known and not important for this question. File1 and file2 are binary files and **should not be converted to text or strings**. I have sanity checked that the first N bytes of file1 hashed matches the hash1*

### The how:

For an input file, read a chunk of N bytes from (start of file) to N, then write the chunk to a new file. Then read a chunk of N bytes from (start of file)+1 byte to N+1 byte, write, read (start of file)+2 bytes to N+2 bytes, write and so on.

In C# I have the following code that splits the entire file into chunks: (Which I will modify to only split out the first chunk at a later date)

```
    public static void SplitFile(string inputFile, int chunkSize, string path)
    {
        const int BUFFER_SIZE = NUMBER;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

        using (Stream input = File.OpenRead(inputFile))
        {
            int index = 0;
            while (input.Position < input.Length)
            {
                using (Stream output = File.Create(path + index))
                {
                    int remaining = chunkSize, bytesRead;
                    while (remaining > 0 && (bytesRead = input.Read(buffer, 0,
                            Math.Min(remaining, BUFFER_SIZE))) > 0)
                    {
                        output.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        remaining -= bytesRead;
                    }
                }
                index++;
            }
        }
    }
```

### The question:

How do I set an offset so that the chunking starts at a specific byte that is not the start of the file, but starts at the offset byte?

Comment: you can use [Stream.Position](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.position?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Or [Stream.Seek](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.seek).